# Where Is The Wifi Password Stored On Windows 7

Tags: windows-7

I have a computer with Ubuntu and windows 7. On the windows side I do not have administrative privileges. However on the Ubuntu side I have full control. So I need to know were the username and password are stored on the windows side. I have full access to the C drive of the windows 7 side.

Comment: Why can't you just reset your router's Wifi password? if it's not your router, why can't you ask the owner for the password? if you can't ask the owner, you are not authorized to connect to the network and [depending on where you live](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legality_of_piggybacking) bypassing security measures could be a criminal offense

Comment: Cross posted (and answered on) http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/33596/how-do-i-find-out-the-username-and-password-of-wifi-windows-7/33598#33598

Answer (score 4):

Viewing Your Wireless Password From an Already Connected Machine

To view your wireless network password we need to get to the settings for your network adapter, so press the Win + R keyboard combination and type ncpa.cpl in the run box, then hit the enter key.
[image]

You will now see all the network adapters in your machine, right-click on the wireless one and select Status from the context menu.
[image]

When the Wi-Fi Status dialog loads up, click on the Wireless Properties button.
[image]

Then you will need to switch over to the Security tab.
[image]

Finally, check the Show characters checkbox to reveal your password.
[image]

That’s all there is to it.

Comment: i don't have administrative access on the windows side.

Answer (score 1):

Using procmon + WirelessKeyView it seems it is located in

C:\ProgramData\Microsoft\Wlansvc\Profiles\Interfaces\{CLASSID}\{CLASSID}.xml